# MySQL / PHP - Storing parameters in a database table: Good or bad idea?

Tags: php, mysql

So far I store all the relevant parameters that I need for my website as variables in a php file; then I point to this file through a `require`statement in each page that needs those parameters.
This is most of times good and easy to mantain, but sometimes I need to change those variables "on the fly" and I feel the need of some sort of web-panel where I can change them even more easily (I'm thinking to a web page with a form to update the parameters).
So I've created a table in my MySQL database to store parameters (basically, this table has two columns: `ParamName` and `ParamValue`; I've stored the parameter names as a varchar **without the $ sign at the beginning**), in order to create the web-panel I've in my mind.

I was thinking to extract all the parameters names and values using this query:

```
$query=$mysqli->query('select * from parameters');
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$ParamName=$row["ParamName"];
$$ParamName=$row["ParamValue"]; }
```

- Is this a good or a bad idea?
- What are the main issues I could encounter doing so (in terms of security, too)?
- How deprecable and dangerous is the use of `$$ParamName`?
- I'd better change my mind or can I proceed this way?

EDIT: I changed `mysql_` syntax into `mysqli_` as suggested.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: bad idea. never pollute your variable space like that. what if you, after a 24 hour coding binge, create a ParamName called `_POST`? or even worse, `_SERVER`? Now you've got a pretty major problem.

Comment: It is poor application design to cram the global variable space filled with named variables. A better way to do this would be to create a single variable or object called something like "config" and use that. I would advise you to split this into two sets "config" and "settings" and only load the settings from a database. "config" would handle things like your database connection information, server names, or anything that needs to be kept secure.

Comment: When I created my website files I started from VERY old files (I know, bad idea) which contained the old `mysql_` functions), and I keep using it though it was deprecate (very bad idea); then I think I'll start from the migration to `mysqli`: is there any tool that can help me in this operation?

Answer (score 1):

Using arbitrary values in a database as variable references is **highly** risky. What you'd want to do is fetch the data from your key/value store into a self-contained associative array and use that instead.

You also do not want to be using `mysql_query` for anything these days. Please, put that thing away.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameters are all constants that will not be changed over time, it is faster to use a single file that stores them as constants in a simple associative array.

If these parameters will change, using a database that specializes in key-value stores might be more useful for you instead of using a standard relational database.

If you cannot change your database from a relational database, or you are not changing the values often, it would be faster to cache them using something like memcached.